# C++ Call Function After Certain Time Period - Without Boost

Tags: c++, function, timer, call, ogre

I need to be able set a timer for X amount of milliseconds then have it call a function when it expires.

I've looked around and I've seen some solutions using Boost\asio but I am not able to use Boost.

Ideally I'd like the solution to work on Windows and Linux. It's a tall order, I know!

Does anyone know how I'd go about this?

Edit: The program is interactive so I cannot put the thread to sleep. And I would rather not use a solution that uses spinning i.e. `while(enough time hasn't elapsed) { }`

Comment: Are you using a GUI framework? Is this even a GUI program? If it's a console program, is it interactive, or not? You haven't given us much information here.

Comment: Too many unknowns to answer. At at rate, check this out - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial

Comment: I've added more info, not sure what other info I can add.

Comment: @Griffin: Are you using a GUI framework? If so, which one?

Comment: @Greg I'm using OGRE - while it comes with Boost, it's only a subset of the Boost libraries. I'm not able to install the full set of libraries.

Comment: @Griffin: I don't know anything about OGRE. But from what I've read (http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=66059) you can either use its own event loop, or use your own. Which are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Even if so useful and simple it's not portable, Windows and Linux uses different threading libraries so you have to write something like this:

```
#if defined WIN32
 // Timer for Windows: it uses SetTimer
#endif
#if defined __LINUX__
 // Timer for Linux: it uses settimer
#endif
```

Code isn't so short to write here so look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644901%28VS.85%29.aspx) for Windows timer. On Windows you may consider, instead of `SetTimer()`, to use the more simple `PostMessageDelayed()`. It'll use even less resources.
For Linux you can write something like this:

```
void test_timer()
{
 signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
 alarm(60); // 1 minute, granularity is 1 second
}

void alarm_handler(int signo)
{
 if (signo == SIGALRM)
 {
   // Time elapsed
 }
}
```

**Addition**
If you have to write a portable library maybe the idea to use SetTimer() for the Windows version is pretty ugly. For Windows you may **consider** to create a background thread then make it sleep for the required time (so you'll do everything without any Windows message).

Comment: alarm_handler is undefined/. bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [setittimer](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/setitimer/).